# "java -version" not working in command prompt

Tags: java, grails

I downloaded this [Java JDK](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp) and installed it.

But when I go to the command prompt to check the version, it says it's not recognized.

Is anyone else experiencing this issue with the latest Java?

I might not have installed the right version. I need the java that works with [grails](http://www.grails.org/Installation)

```
C:\>java
'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\>java -version
'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\>
```

when i do a search on my computer for java, it does not find anything

Comment: You should copy/paste exactly what you're putting into the command prompt and exactly what's coming back.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Windows 2k8 R2 server- 
For both java [-option] or %JAVA_HOME% to work in the command line you need the following:

In Control Panel->System and Security->System->Advanced system setting->Advanced->Environment Variables->System Variables

Edit the Path variable and add a ";" after the last value and add the the path to the Java bin directory:
e.g.- C:\Progra~2\Java\jre6\bin\

Add the JAVA_HOME Variable with the value set to the path for the java executable:
e.g.- C:\Progra~2\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe

Comment: I define %JAVA_HOME%, then I put %JAVA_HOME%\bin in my PATH variable.  That way, if I need to change JAVA_HOME, I only have to do it in one place.  Also, I am not a fan of putting JAVA_HOME in the Program Files directory.  I've had issues with this before because of the space in the file name.

Answer (score 10):

Press simultaneously the "windows" and "pause" buttons on your keyboard, this will bring up the System Preferences dialog.
In the Advanced tab, find Environment Variables.

Then, in the User (upper) section, create or update the following two variables :

- JAVA_HOME = where you put your JDK, eg. C:/Java/SDK
- PATH = %JAVA_HOME%/bin

Close the dialogs.

Then, in a new command-line console, try "javac -version" and see if it's detected.
It's important that you use a new console, because environment variables are read only when the console is launched.

Answer (score 10):

Java is typically installed (on Windows) as `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk<version>`

That installation directory has a subdirectory `bin` which you need to append to your PATH environment variable via the control panel. Then, the commands like `java`, `javac` etc. will be available on the command line.

BTW, the same is true for Grails.

Answer (score 7):

Is the -version flag not recognized, or is the "java" command not recognized?  One way to test this is just to type 'java' by itself and run it and see what happens.

If the command is not recognized, [make sure that the JDK's install path is in your windows PATH](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml).  If not, you won't be able to use any of the java executables from the command prompt.  [Here's another link](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/classpath.html) that may help out.

Comment: im not finding java at all on my computer, but when i run installation again it says that it's installed

Comment: @every_answer_gets_a_point - Read the install path document I linked in my answer.  It explains the problem that you are having.

Answer (score 4):

You need to manually add the path to javac.exe and java.exe to your operating system path. The Java installation program doesn't do that for you.

Answer (score 3):

You most likely don't have java.exe in your system's PATH variable.

Comment: im not finding java at all on my computer, but when i run installation again it says that it's installed

Comment: It's either in "C:\Program Files\Java" or "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java" depending on the version of Windows you are running and the version of Java you installed.

Answer (score 3):

**For Linux:**

check $PATH and $JAVA_HOME. You can configure it in /etc/environment

From console you can check it like:

```
$ echo $PATH
```

**For Windows:**

My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables
Check there PATH.

From console you can check it like:

```
echo %PATH%
```

Answer (score 2):

You should have a **Java** icon in Windows Control Panel. Locate the *Java* tab and click the *View* button. That will show you the path to the Java executables.

Last but not least, make sure you have restarted the computer so changes in the PATH variable can take effect.

Comment: You don't need to restart the computer, just open a new command window.  Or you can always just issue a "set PATH=C:\path\to\java;%PATH%" to update the path in your current window.

Comment: That's fine to use Java from the command line but he probably wants to use Java from another tool.

Answer (score 1):

You installed the JDK.  Isn't java.exe part of the JRE?  Do you have that installed?

Comment: you might be right, which version do i need for grails: http://www.grails.org/Installation ?

Comment: java.exe is part of the JDK, too, and a JRE is usually installed as part of the JDK.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your system variables in the environment variables are not set properly. Follow the steps in the link below. Finally, make sure the path component in system variables has only one JDK path. Delete other JDK paths that you won't use.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Answer (score 1):

You might have installed a previous or older version of Java so you can just uninstall it and directly download JDK from [Java JDK](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk17-windows)

I was also facing the same issue but when I downloaded and installed the latest version the issue was resolved.

Also uninstall any other Java versions which may be present in the program files.

To get to know other versions which may be present in your computer use Windows File Explorer to go to:
*Files* > *Windows C* > *Program Files* > *Java*

All the JDK and JRE you have will be listed there. Uninstall any other Java versions other than what you installed. And then make sure you have set the path variable of the JDK.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was incorrect line in the PATH

(1) Check PATH: Type "Edit System Environment Variables" on the search -> System Properties -> Advance -> Environment Variables -> System variables -> Path

(2) On the list, mine was `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath` so I just add `\` at the end (the exe files in the `javapath` folder)

OS: Windows 10 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

IF you set the PATH and it's not showing up in cmd when you run %PATH%, try restarting your computer.