# Java -version shows 1.3 when I updated the classpath to c:\java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin

Tags: java

I need to run a java -jar on command line and so installed jdk6 but whenever i do java -version in command line it still shows the old version (1.3) How do I update it to show the latest version ??

Comment: possible duplicate of ["java -version" not working in command prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380572/java-version-not-working-in-command-prompt)  (Not an exact match of the symptoms, but the real problem and the solution are the same.)

Answer (score 2):

Add the new Java bin folder to your path. And remove any other java references from your path.

Answer (score 2):

You should set the `PATH` environment variable. On the command prompt, do:

```
> set JAVA_HOME=c:\java\jdk1.6.0_20
> set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
```

Now doing `java -version` should give you the expected version information.

Answer (score 0):

The JDK install does not update the default Java installation on the system.

Go to http://java.com/en/download/installed.jsp and use the suggested installation procedure there when it finds that your default Java is outdated.

Comment: Which suggested installation procedure are you referring to?  I couldn't see an obvious "how to install Java" on that page.  A link to the actual instructions would he more helpful.