# Don't see java version 14 in command prompt

Tags: java, sdk

I installed `jdk-14.0.1_windows-x64_bin.exe` from https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk14-downloads.html.

I added `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin` to my `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME` variables.
After this I start a new command prompt and type `java -version`, and I see the list below, but I don't see `java version "14.0.1"`, why not?

> java version "1.8.0_251" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_251-b08)
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.251-b08, mixed mode)

I already checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380572/java-version-not-working-in-command-prompt).

Comment: can you check if java 8 is still in your `PATH`? if it's there, remove it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you add a new version of Java to your `PATH` to use it as default you should also make sure that it is the **only one** in your `PATH`.

in this case, you already had Java 8 in your `PATH` and it was being used as default instead of the new Java 14, so the solution is to remove Java 8 from the `PATH`.